# See code coverage of a specific file

Tags: phpunit, code-coverage

I would like to know if it's possible to generate a code coverage from one single file. Let's say I am writing tests for a class `BankAccount`, it would be handy if i could from command line do something like

```
phpunit BankAccount.php --create-coverage-for-this-file-only
```

Does anyone have experience experience with this?

Thaks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with the `--filter` option.

```
phpunit -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On --coverage-html tests/_report/ --filter=BankAccount
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the XML file, you can include the files or directories you want to process, and exclude the ones you do not.  [PHPUnit Manual Entry](http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html)

```
<filter>
    <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
        <file>BankAccount.php</file>
        <directory suffix=".class">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".fn">.</directory>
        <directory suffix=".php">.</directory>
        <exclude>
            <directory>ExternalLibraries</directory>
        </exclude>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
```